# How to skip the ToS page to access my WhatsApp messages?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I found my old Blackphone BP1 with all my data including my WhatsApp conversations. I can access all my WhatsApp pictures, voice, and documents through USB but not my chats. When I launch the app, the ToS page appears.

[image: WhatsApp ToS page]
<sub>(source: [eff.org](https://ssd.eff.org/files/2016/04/26/tos.png))</sub>

- I can't root my phone to get the private key (as it's a BP1).
- I can't "Agree and continue" and receive the SMS as the SIM card is not active anymore.
- I tried to extract it on an unrooted phone with [WhatsApp-Key-DB-Extractor](https://github.com/EliteAndroidApps/WhatsApp-Key-DB-Extractor) with no success.
- I also tried a few older WhatsApp versions.

How to skip this ToS page in order to access my old WhatsApp messages?

Comment: Wild guess.. install old version and set the device date to say an year ago? When the ToS wasn't announced

Comment: I tried with older version, the oldest being v2.7.5813.

Comment: With an earlier date on device ?

Comment: Yes, I changed the date to 2012.

Comment: Maybe this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.omnicrypt) on its own or in combination with GitHub extractor can help?

Comment: Nope, you need a rooted phone (and I can't root it because it's a blackphone) or to extract the key with WhatsApp-Key-DB-Extractor to get omni-crypt to work.